# Strange behavior rake db:drop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

Performs rake db: drop .. and at first he will remove, and then displays the result, which initially enters into error! `Couldn't drop db_name: # <Mysql2::Error: Unknown database'db_name'>`.. basically the same thing with the create .. First do the creation, then write that base still exists!

Comment: rake db:drop:all fails with same error.